# Unknown Host Exception thrown by HttpClient.execute

Tags: java, android, http, android-manifest

i am trying to get data from a webpage on my server.However when i run this code it always fails at httpClient.execute()

```
String flixURL=("http://myserver.com:6718/cgi-bin/log.pl?zip=" + zippy);            
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),flixURL,5).show();

DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(flixURL);
ResponseHandler<String> resHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
System.out.println("resHandler"+resHandler);

try {                
String page = httpClient.execute(httpGet, resHandler);                      
System.out.println("page"+page);
} 
catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
{
e.printStackTrace();System.out.println(e);
} 
catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();System.out.println(e);
}
```

Debugger told me it is possible UnknownHostException. I have tried different URLs as well still the issues persists.

Android Manifest file is like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.andtwi"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".AndTwitterActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
              <activity android:name=".screen2" android:label="Screen2">
      </activity>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Can anyone give me hint where is the problem. Thanks..

Comment: http:/myserver.com:6718/cgi-bin/log.pl?zip=
You forgot a '/' at the beginning of the URL

Comment: What @VitoShadow said really. Your URL is incorrect, hence UnknownHostException.

Comment: @all i updated the URL. It was correct. I typoed when copying here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move this line

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Outside `<application>` tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.andtwi"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".AndTwitterActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
              <activity android:name=".screen2" android:label="Screen2">
      </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Voila... it Worked... Thanks LAS_Vegas .. Hey how do you know my winter holiday destination :) 

BTW.. can you please explain why you asked me to move that code out of those tags... Thanks

Comment: It's a common mistake, permissions doesn't work when they are inside :) See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html for details.